# Javascript sound activation for Iphone4

Tags: javascript

I am looking for some Javascript code that will activate or generate a sound when an event is reached. Activating the ring tones within the Iphone4 with Safari will also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript audio object. As for activating ringtones, that to the best of my knowledge is impossible from javascript.

```
var sound = new Audio("sound.mp3");
sound.play()
```

Comment: Do I start the code with <Script> and end it with </Script>  Do I have to have this sound.mp3 file installed somewhere on the phone?  Will .mp3 files play on the iphone?

Comment: @Todd The file should be in the webserver, and yes, it should be between script tags. This answer works for most audio file types including .mp3s

Comment: Thanks!  It works fine on my windows pc.  However it will not work on my iIhone4s when i open the html site.   It just shows a blank page.

Comment: @Todd If you have safari on your computer you can plug in your phone after going into Settings>Safari>Advanced and turning on web inspector on your iphone. Then you should be able to open the web inspector on your computer to view any error messages.